# Are esters and amides soluble in cold acids/bases?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, solubility, alcohols, esters

The main problem I have is that we say amines are soluble in acids because they are bases, and they will thus react with acids. But if A reacts with B, how does that imply A is soluble in B? Yes, esters and amides do not react with cold acids/bases, but why does that imply that they are insoluble? Ethanol does not react with water, but it's soluble in it.

Comment: This could be six to twelve separate questions, combinatorially mixing (esters/amides/alcohols) and (cold/hot) (acids/bases).

Comment: Edited. Please see the new question.